# Iscroll causes links inside the scrolling parent to become unclickable on touch devices

Tags: javascript, mobile, iscroll

I'm trying to use the iscroll plugin (https://github.com/cubiq/iscroll) to add scrolling to a div. I am finding that it renders links inside the scrolling parent unclickable. Disabling the plugin fixes it.

At first I thought it was something to do with `-webkit-transform` but that doesn't seem to be the case as I created a standalone fiddle with it in.

A demo can be found here - **http://jsfiddle.net/5Frv4/**. Go to it using a mobile webkit browser to see the issue in action.

Iscroll is initialised with a few simple options:

```
var menuScroll = new IScroll('#menu', {
    mouseWheel: true,
    scrollbars: 'custom',
    interactiveScrollbars: true,
});
```

I'm not sure what I can do to get around this issue. Does anyone know anything else I could try?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try iScroll's option

```
click: true
```

> To override the native scrolling iScroll has to inhibit some default browser behaviors, such as mouse clicks. If you want your application to respond to the click event you have to explicitly set this option to true. Please note that it is suggested to use the custom tap event instead (see below).
>   http://iscrolljs.com/#configuring